# Passing multiple values in Javascript OnClick, using those values in specific ways

Tags: javascript, html

While I've done some Javascript coding, I consider myself a more novice, Frankenstein-type coder, basically cutting and pasting with trial and error to see if I can get something to work...just a heads up on my honest assessment of my experience level.

I've got a unique thing I'm developing for, and hoping to get some help with Javascript.  Here's what I'm trying / need to do: for a webpage based kiosk presentation, I'm using one HTML webpage, but with multiple  sections whose visibility toggles on/off based on a Javascript I currently have that works fine.  (I don't want to / can't use regular HTML pages with links because of how it ends up running).

The only problem with the above issue is that there's no easy way to create a 'back' or 'previous page' link for an end page that may have multiple ways to get to it.  It won't 'know' where the user came from.

So here's what I'd like to do: pass 2 variables through my OnClick javascript function, the DIV name that needs to toggle on/off ... AND a 2nd variable of the current visible DIV name so that the next DIV that toggles on can 'remember' what the previous (and now invisible) DIV was so that there can be an accurate 'back' button.

Here's some sample code:

Each DIV section that turns on an off is setup like this:

```
<div id="sectionName" class="content">
</div>
```

These DIVs have buttons/links that are setup like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('sectionName');"></a>
```

These run a Javacript:

```
function toggleVisibility(selectedTab) {

     var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

     for(var i=0; i<content.length; i++) {
          if(content[i].id == selectedTab) {
                content[i].style.display = 'block';
          } else {
                content[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
     }

}
```

So what I'm hoping is that there is a way to do something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('sectionNameToTurnOn, 'rememberThisSectionName');"></a>
```

So that when that is clicked, the next DIV that turns on could also include a Javascript generated link based on that passed variable, something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('rememberThisSectionName');">Previous<br>Menu</a>
```

I'm aware that Javascript toggling of DIVs on and off may not allow the generation of a dynamic Javascript link like the one I'm describing above, so I'm throwing this out there for some help from other, far more experienced programmers.  Ideally, I'd like to try and fit everything into what I've created so far, so I don't have to start over from scratch.  Any ideas?

Please reference this sample page:

www.gs3creative.com/test/

Comment: Why don't you just save the value you want in a global variable?

Comment: Especially with your background, wouldn't it be a better approach to use an existing "single page web application" framework instead of clumsily trying to build one yourself?!

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for me would be to render two content pages on a HTML page and show and hide content when needed from a onlick handler via javascript in your CSS add a class:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById("theObject").className = "visible";
}
```

CSS:

```
// Switch between the content adding the  classes and removing the old class 

.visible{
    display:none;
} 

.show{
    display:block;
}
```

Another solution using sessions "php" via javascript to hold the variables with in statements.

```
<?php if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_is where_variable'] = "im on page div 1";
}
```

This could also be done through js anyways.

```
javascript have a conditional statement using your $_SESSION vars;

if (variable == "im on page div 1" ){
   // your functions
}else if ( variable == "im on page div 1"){
  // another function

}

Create your click handler to update the variables in the session.
```

Comment: Not sure this is addressing what I'm asking... I can already make the DIVs appear and disappear...I need to add a 'breadcrumb' so that the 'Previous Page' link works...

Answer (score 0):

You could use location hashes (mypage.html#mydivid) and then use `history.back()` to handle 'back' navigation.

To stitch up the div's showing on the correct hash value....

```
var oldHash = '';

// fires when the hash changes
function hash_changed() {
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', ''); // get the div ID
    var div = document.getElementById(hash); // find the content div on the page
    var allDivs = document.getElementByClassName('content'); // get all of the content divs

    // hide all the content divs
    for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
        var thisDiv = allDivs[i];
        thisDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // only show the right one
    div.style.display = 'block';       
}

// this triggers the event
setInterval(function() {

    // if the hash has changed, fire the function
    if (oldHash != location.hash) {
        oldHash = location.hash;
        hash_changed();
    }

}, 100); // call every 100 ms so that there is no lag
```

So if you set the navigation to 'mypage.html#sectionName' it would hide all other div's of the class 'content' and then only show the div with the ID of 'sectionName'.

Comment: Michael, thanks...but keep in mind I'm not reloading the HTML ... I'm just toggling DIVs on and off...  check it out:   http://www.gs3creative.com/test/

Comment: That is all good mate, this will not reload the HTML adding a hash to the location usually makes the browser scroll so that the item addressed is at the top of the screen. Because we are hiding everything on the page other than the div you want this scrolling will not happen and it will count as a navigation change in the browser. With the navigation change you will be able to take advantage of the built in browser functions of back and forward